# JavaFx - Tab closable button

Tags: tabs, javafx

I've created a Tab and added it to the TabPane. I have set its closable property to TRUE. How can I get the close button to show?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I was looking for answer long time, answer is very simple.

Just have to set TabClosingPolicy

TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB

Answer (score 9):

In fxml file property can be added in tabplane as tabClosingPolicy="SELECTED_TAB" or "ALL_TABS"